# Mantener ventana de turtle abierta al terminar de dibujar

Tags: python

Utilizo Python en PyCharm y estaba haciendo dibujos con `turtle` y no tengo idea como hacer que se quede el dibujo en pantalla, ya que se quita cada vez que termina de ejecutar el dibujo.

Éste es mi código:

```
def poligono(lado,n):

    for i in range(n):
        forward(lado)
        right(360/n)

def poligonos():

    for i in range(3,11):
        poligono(100,i)

def espiral():

    for i in range(10,300,5):
        poligono(i,3)
        right(10)

espiral()
```

Comment: amigo porfa poner tu codigo y saber que tienes hecho hasta el momento y asi poder ayudarte

Comment: Listo amigo, gracias por la recomendacion

Comment: amigo te falta ponerle el `mainloop()` dentro del main para que mantenga la ventana ejecutando yo alguna vez cree alguno pero solicita el tamaño en px del cuadro que realizara

Answer (score 2):

Se cierra porque el proceso termina su ejecución. Puedes llamar a turtle.mainloop()/turtle.done() para lanzar el mainloop de Tkinter. Dicha llamada debes hacerla al final de todo. Además puedes usar `turtle.onkeypress` para salir al pulsar una tecla:

```
from turtle import forward, right, onkeypress, listen, bye, done


def poligono(lado,n):
    for i in range(n):
        forward(lado)
        right(360/n)

def poligonos():
    for i in range(3,11):
        poligono(100,i)

def espiral():
    for i in range(10,20,5):
        poligono(i,3)
        right(10)

espiral()
onkeypress(bye, 'q')
listen()
done()
```

La ventana se quedará abierta hasta que pulses <kbd>q</kbd> (elije la tecla que más te guste..)

> **Nota**: no usar `mainloop/done` si se ejecuta desde IDLE o mediante un intérprete interactivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, muy útil

Answer (score 1):

Esto al final del código me dio resultado a mí:

```
turtle.Screen().exitonclick()
```

`exitonclick()` es una función que hace que se entre en mainloop hasta que se pulse el ratón. No necesita argumentos. [Puedes leer más información en este enlace](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-turtle-exitonclick/).